# GCM not delivery if internet off

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Why if internet of receiver when notification start is inactive And Then It Will turned on the notification neve r arrived?  Sorry for My English

here my php:

```
<?php include_once 'connection.php';

$myconn = connectToDatabase();
$ricevente = $_POST['ricevente'];
$mittente = $_POST['mittente'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$api = getCode($ricevente);
$Authorization='AIzaSyBfrXTHDg_TDoD1dKgoSbeTNH2heV_aq30';
$headers = array(
'Authorization: key=' .$Authorization ,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);


$fields = array(    
    'delay_while_idle' => true,
    'time_to_live' =>  2419200, 
    'registration_ids' => array( 0 => $api),
    'data' => array(
        'type'=>"$type",
        'id'=>"$id",
        'mittente'=>"$mittente",
        'data'=>"$data"
    ),
);
print_r($fields['data']);
echo sendNotification($headers,$fields);

function sendNotification($h,$f){

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $h);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $f ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
}

function getCode($ricevente){
    $myconn = connectToDatabase();
    $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE phone = '$ricevente'";
    $result = mysqli_query($myconn, $sql);
    if($result){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        mysqli_close($myconn);
        return $row['api'];
    }
    $phone2 = '';
    if($ricevente[0] == '+'){
        $phone2 = substr($ricevente, 3, strlen($ricevente));

    }
    else{
        $phone2 = "+39".$ricevente;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE phone = '$phone2'";
    $result = mysqli_query($myconn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    mysqli_close($myconn);
    return $row['api'];

}?>
```

here my java code

```
 public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.w("Entro","Arriva");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
            for (String key : keys) {
                try {
                    json.put(key, extras.get(key));
                }
                catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(extras.get("type").toString().equals("chiamata")){
                int idNotifica = Integer.parseInt(extras.get("id").toString());
                String mittente = extras.get("mittente").toString();
                String data = extras.get("data").toString();
                Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("toOpen", "2");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        myIntent,
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(Utils.getContactName(mittente, this) + " ti ha cercato!")
                        .setContentText("Ciao, ti ho cercato il " + data)
                        .setTicker("Chiamata ricevuta")
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notify)
                        .setSound(uri)
                        .build();

                notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                int id = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);
                id += (int)Math.random() * 100;
                notificationManager.notify(id, myNotification);
                GetNotify gt = new GetNotify();
                gt.setId(id);
                gt.setMittente(mittente);
                gt.setCtx(this);
                gt.setData(data);
                GetDatabase gd = new GetDatabase(this);
                gd.createBook(gt);
                sendNotification(idNotifica, mittente);
            }
            else{
                int id = Integer.parseInt(extras.get("id").toString());
                String data = extras.get("data").toString();
                SentDatabase db = new SentDatabase(this);
                List<SentNotify> list = db.getAllBooks();
                for(SentNotify c : list){
                    if(c.getId()== id){
                        Log.d("r", data);
                        c.setLetto(data);
                    }
                }
                db.deleteAll();
                db.addAll(list);
            }
        }
    }
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(int id, String mittente){

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.studionacarlo.com/applicazione/sendNotifica.php");
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String result = "";
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
        int i = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);
        i += (int)Math.random() * 100;
        Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String formattedCurrentDate = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate);
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat simpleTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String formattedCurrentTime = simpleTimeFormat.format(currentDate);
        String x =formattedCurrentDate+" alle "+formattedCurrentTime;
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "setletto"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", String.valueOf(id)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ricevente", mittente));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", x));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Add your data
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String htmlResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        result = htmlResponse;
        Log.w("Stampa ricevuta", result);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

here my manifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name="GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.giuseppezappia.Services" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


   <permission android:name="permission.C2D_MESSAGE"          android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Please help me because i don't know why they will note delivery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [lifetime of a message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#lifetime) section of the GCM documentation discusses several factors as to why it may not have been "delivered"

Basically, a GCM-connected device that's idle will be delivered right away unless `delay_while_idle` is set to true. A device not connected to GCM will be stored in the server until a connection has been established.

Also, don't forget to [obtain a registration token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#receiving-messages-on-an-android-client-app) for the client app for your Instance Service in your manifest.